# How to refer parent template in quickform attribute _id

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, ecmascript-6, meteor-blaze

Consider Below Code.

```
{{#each assignments}}
  {{#with eachClientDetails}}
    {{#quickRemoveButton collection=assignment _id=this._id }}
       Delete
    {{/quickRemoveButton}}
  {{/with}}
{{/each}}
```

In above code, I am iterating each `assignment` and each `assignment` has single `Client` Detail. With each `Client` Detail I am adding Delete button.

**Helper:**

```
eachClientDetails(){
    var client = Clients.find({_id: this.clientId}).fetch()[0];
    console.log(client);
    return client;
}
```

But the problem is, while assigning attributes to `_id` of `quickForm`, I can only assign data from current context(i.e. `this._id`). All I need is to access context of `assignment` (desired like `_id=../_id`). But I get below error,

```
Can only use `this` at the beginning of a path.
Instead of `foo.this` or `../this`, just write `foo` or `..`.
```

Is it possible using any helper and stuff to get the parent templates `_id`

Comment: Doesn't `_id=_id` work? You're already in `eachClientDetails` context, so there is no need of `../`

Comment: i want to access id of `assignments`

Comment: Ah, then why do you use `#with eachClientDetails`?

Comment: to show details of `Client` associated with specific `assignment`

Comment: Sorry, it isn't clear from your question, _where_ exactly do you show these `Client` details.

Comment: `eachClientDetails` is a helper which then fetches the client from `assignment`'s _id.

Comment: Ah, then this helper is able to add another field, like `parentId: ...` and set it to `assignment`'s `_id`, so you would be able to use this `parentId` in `#quickRemoveButton`

Comment: it would be great if you show me how? while I am updating question with helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue with overwriting contexts could be solved by using `#each in` and `#let` instead of `#each` and `#with`:

```
{{#each assignment in assignments}}
  {{#let client=(eachClientDetails assignment)}}
    {{#quickRemoveButton collection=assignment _id=assignment._id }}
       Delete {{client.name}}
    {{/quickRemoveButton}}
  {{/let}}
{{/each}}
```

Here, `{{client.name}}` has been added just to show how to access `client`'s fields.

And helper's code:

```
eachClientDetails(assignment){
    var client = Clients.findOne({_id: assignment.clientId});
    console.log(client);
    return client;
}
```

Comment: Plus, using `#each in` and `#let` instead of `#each` and `#with` is a good practice recommended by the BlazeJS documentation. http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html#Each-and-With

Comment: @GaëtanRouziès Yes, thanks, I forgot to mention that :)

Comment: @styx: thanks for reply. I learnt something new today. I'll check it and let you know.